# Receiving error with decimal data type mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, import, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE WLPortfolio
(
    symbolID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    symbol_userID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    symbol default NULL,
    holding default NULL,
    amount decimal(12,2) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (symbolID)
);
```

I am receiving this error when I try to import my database into phpMyAdmin as well as via ssh (corresponding code above):

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 33: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default NULL,
    holding default NULL,
        amount decimal(12,2) default NULL,
    ' at line 5
```

The partition in error is the decimal data type. To my knowledge decimal wat I have done should keep the "amount" value 12 characters long with the decimal values going into 2 characters. Which I believe is correct syntax, yet I still receive this error.

I have tried changing around the default value if for some reason this was causing the error or if compatibility issue was an error. But to no avail.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**Completely missed declaring values holding and symbol, rookie mistake -_- Thanks guys**

Comment: your script is completely wrong. Where is the types for the columns symbol and holding??? =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define types for all fields.

```
CREATE TABLE WLPortfolio
(
    symbolID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    symbol_userID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    symbol MEDIUMINT default NULL,
    holding MEDIUMINT default NULL,
    amount decimal(12,2) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (symbolID)
);
```

Comment: Yeh I just realised... Thanks for helping. Massive oversight on my behalf.